# Kindly help me resolve below mentioned error? I am beginning to Opencv in Eclispe

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

```
00:00:35 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Working ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv" "-IC:\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv2 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o src\\abc.o ..\\src\\abc.cpp" 
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

00:00:35 Build Finished (took 100ms)
```

Comment: Lookup "g++.exe: fatal error: no input files" and see where you get from that.

Comment: This is my Code:#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
    {
      printf( "No image data \n" );
      return -1;
    }

  namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Display Image", image );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}

Comment: It's impossible to read code in a single line like that. Please in the future update your answer with the code, or throw it in hastebin

Comment: TS: you meant the question not the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The quotation marks are a problem.

Check your compiler settings so that the -I... and the following parameters in the g++ command line are not enclosed in a single pair of double quotation marks. In this way g++ thinks it is just one parameter.

Comment: Bro, I am beginner to this and how don't know how to compiler setting in eclipse CDT

Comment: Go to the properties/options/preferences of your project. Find the compiler settings there. Somewhere there you have a line with compiler command line arguments where you have extra quotes in the front and in the back. It may look something like this: http://janaxelson.com/articles/eclipse/compiler_settings.png

Comment: Its is like this     -I"C:\opencv\build\include\opencv" -I"C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11

Comment: do I have change above line?

Comment: ok, the second -I option is missing a terminating quote. It is added automatically at the very end, which breaks your compilation process. Add the second quotation mark after the first occurence of the 'opencv2' string on that line. Does it help?

Comment: Change to I"C:\opencv\build\include\opencv" -I"C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11

Comment: Thank you , Thank you very much.  Your inputs helped me and finally i got output.